# Flipping bits without getting negative number

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation

How can I flip the bits of an integer without changing its sign? For example, how can I flip `"1010"` (10<sub>10</sub>) to `"0101"` (5<sub>10</sub>)?

Bitwise negative operator results in negative number: `~10` (`~0b1010`) → `-11` (`0b0101`).

Comment: if `~10 -> 5 (~1010 -> 0101)` then should`~5 -> 10 (~0101 -> 1010)` ? or `~5 -> 2 (~101 -> 010)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean strings, then:

```
"1010".tr("01", "10") # => "0101"
```

If you mean numbers, then:

```
10.to_s(2).tr("01", "10").to_i(2) # => 5
```

Answer (score 13):

You can flip the bits via XOR:

```
    1010 (decimal 10)
XOR 1111 (decimal 15)
  = 0101 (decimal 5)
```

In Ruby:

```
0b1010 ^ 0b1111 #=> 5
```

The number of 1's corresponds to the number of bits, therefore you could use:

```
num  = 0b1010
num ^ (1 << num.bit_length) - 1
#=> 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it fits for your needs, but you can just flip binary string char by char like this:

```
"1010".chars.map { |i| i == "1" ? "0" : "1" }.join #=> "0101"
```

Upd:

How about this:

```
a = ~10
(a.bit_length - 1).downto(0).map { |i| a[i] }.join #=> "0101"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible with bitwise complement (~) operator?

Comment: Or simply `'1010'.tr('01', '10')`

Comment: You should accept Stefan's answer, I was about to delete this, because his approach is better.